# How to animate a circular background color for a `Composable`?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My goal is to have a `Composable` fun (or `Modifier` extension) which I can call from another `Composable` method which will add a circular red background to it. The background should grow and shrink slowly by 10%.

This is what it looks now:
[image]

The red background does not animate and I would like to know what is wrong with my code. The content itself should remain the same, the red background should only grow and shrink:

```
@Composable
fun PulsatingCircle(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
    val scale by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 1f,
        targetValue = 2f, // 2 to see if it does really something quickly
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(1700, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
        )
    )

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
                val currentHeight = placeable.height
                val currentWidth = placeable.width
                val newDiameter = maxOf(currentHeight, currentWidth)
                val newScale = newDiameter * scale

                layout(newScale.toInt(), newScale.toInt()) {
                    placeable.placeRelative(
                        ((newScale - currentWidth) / 2).toInt(),
                        ((newScale - currentHeight) / 2).toInt()
                    )
                }
            }
            .background(color = Color.Red, shape = CircleShape)
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want your Composable to grow as well? Since you change Composable dimensions with ` layout(newScale.toInt(), newScale.toInt())` it will push any other siblings as it grows and circle will never touch siblings when scaled. If you use Modifier.drawBehind{} with scale only background will grow while not having any effect on total size of Composable, this one is easier to implement if having another sibling is not the concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the purpose of using Layout to move siblings while changing size Modifier.background() should be before Modifier.layout but this can be easily animated Modifier.drawBehind{drawCircle(Color.Red, radius = size*scale)}

With Layout you can use Offset too If you don't want content to move while parent with Magenta border is growing as

[image]

```
@Composable
fun PulsatingCircle(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "")
    val scale by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 1f,
        targetValue = 2f, // 2 to see if it does really something quickly
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(1700, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
        ), label = ""
    )

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .border(1.dp, Color.Magenta)
            .background(color = Color.Red, shape = CircleShape)
            .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
                val currentHeight = placeable.height
                val currentWidth = placeable.width
                val newDiameter = maxOf(currentHeight, currentWidth)
                val newScale = newDiameter * scale
                layout(newScale.toInt(), newScale.toInt()) {
                    placeable.placeRelative(
                        ((newScale - currentWidth) / 2).toInt(),
                        ((newScale - currentHeight) / 2).toInt()
                    )
                }
            }

            .border(2.dp, Color.Blue)

    ) {
        content()
    }
}

@Composable
fun PulsatingCircle2(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "")
    val scale by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 1f,
        targetValue = 2f, // 2 to see if it does really something quickly
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(1700, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
        ), label = ""
    )

    var offset by remember {
        mutableStateOf(IntOffset(0, 0))
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .border(2.dp, Color.Magenta)
            .offset {
                offset
            }
            .background(color = Color.Red, shape = CircleShape)
            .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
                val currentHeight = placeable.height
                val currentWidth = placeable.width
                val newDiameter = maxOf(currentHeight, currentWidth)
                val newScale = newDiameter * scale
                offset = IntOffset(
                    -((newScale - currentWidth) / 2).toInt(),
                    -((newScale - currentHeight) / 2).toInt()
                )
                layout(newScale.toInt(), newScale.toInt()) {
                    placeable.placeRelative(
                        ((newScale - currentWidth) / 2).toInt(),
                        ((newScale - currentHeight) / 2).toInt()
                    )
                }
            }

            .border(2.dp, Color.Blue)

    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

With Modifier.drawBehind{}

```
fun Modifier.animateBackground(
    color: Color
) = composed {
    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "")
    val scale by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 1f,
        targetValue = 2f, // 2 to see if it does really something quickly
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(1700, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
        ), label = ""
    )

    Modifier.drawBehind {
        val radius = (size.width.coerceAtLeast(size.height)) / 2
        drawCircle(color = color, radius = radius * scale)
    }
}
```

Demo

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 30.dp, start = 30.dp)

    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .border(2.dp, Color.Cyan)
        ) {
            PulsatingCircle {
                Image(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.People,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .border(2.dp, Color.Cyan)
        ) {
            PulsatingCircle2 {
                Image(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.People,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .border(2.dp, Color.Cyan)
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .zIndex(4f)
                    .animateBackground(Color.Red),
                imageVector = Icons.Default.People,
                contentDescription = null
            )

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
            )
        }
    }
}
```